# Find the internal server error in django-rest framework (thinkster django tutorial)

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am following the following the [thinkster django-angular](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#logging-users-in) tutorial and am currently at the user registration stage. Despite following along with the tutorial word by word, I am getting an `internal server error` when I post something to the rest framework using angular.

However, no debug logs or error messages are shown. Can someone tell me how to get the error message from Django-rest-framework? I searched around but couldn't find anything.

Incase you wish to look at my code :

```
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets

from authentication.models import Account
from authentication.permissions import IsAccountOwner
from authentication.serializers import AccountSerializer


class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

    return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

def create(self, request):
    print "hoorah"
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response({
        'status': 'Bad request',
        'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
    }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from thinkster_django_angular_boilerplate.views import IndexView, TemplateView
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from authentication.views import AccountViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
   url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
   url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

Comment: When there is an error, rest framework returns the entire error page. So save the output to a file and open it in a browser to know the error

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I am posting the message via my browser (a register.html page). For the output nothing changes on the template (though `DEBUG=True` is set in the settings) and I just see the internal server error message on the console and the terminal running the server.

Comment: If `DEBUG=True`, you should not get just internal server error. You should get the entire html code of the error page

Comment: You should be able to access the API through the Browsable API directly with your browser and then try to authenticate. If the error occurs you'll get the aforementioned error page.

Comment: Hi @sudshekhar. This post is 11 months old, but I have the same problem with the same tutorial. Did you find the solution?

Comment: anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could look the solution at here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/

I had the same problem before this, all you need to fix this is just import `status` from rest_framework and `Response` from `rest_framework.response`

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
```